# Знаки препинания в предложениях с плеонастическим употреблением личного местоимения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, выбор-варианта, плеоназм

Какой знак препинания обычно ставится "в предложениях с плеонастическим (излишним) употреблением личного местоимения 3-го лица, дублирующего предшествующее существительное"? (Тьфу ты! Мне этот Розенталь скоро снится будет!)

Answer (score 1):

Вот что написано у Розенталя (и пусть он нам снится — грамотнее будем!):

> Синонимия запятой и тире с сохранением присущих каждому из этих знаков препинания смысловых и интонационных оттенков встречается в ряде случаев:
> 9) в предложениях с плеонастическим (излишним) употреблением личного местоимения 3-го лица, дублирующего предшествующее существительное: *Все эти прошлые годы, все эти воспоминания (— ,) они продолжали существовать.*
> Ср.:
> *Народ, он культуры требует* (Сол.); *Пуля — она в Федотку-то не угодит, а кого-нибудь со стороны свалит* (Сед.);
> *Слёзы унижения, они были едки* (Фед.); *Мужик — он строгость любит* (Марк.)

Термин "синонимия" в нашем случае — это практически равноправие двух знаков. Так что в таких предложениях **обычно** ставится запятая или тире, выбор же — контекстуальный.

Посмотрела в Нацкорпусе: [*женщины они*](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&req=%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8&g=i_doc&format=html&spp=50&text=lexform&dpp=10&kwsz=5&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal) и [*мужчины они*](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&req=%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8&g=i_doc&format=html&spp=50&text=lexform&dpp=10&kwsz=5&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal).

Мол, женщины ― они прекрасные, нежные, трепетные, ранимые, и без них мы не были бы мужчинами.
Женщины ― они такие легкие, воздушные.
А может быть, она сразу на него глаз положила ― женщины, они ведь стратеги великие.
Жена Люси сгоношила закусок ― женщины, они все умеют.
А скажите, ваши женщины, они вас никогда не ревновали к пишущим машинкам?
Женщины ― они такие фантазерки!
... а женщины, они любят, когда на взгляд мужчины можно положиться.
Но сейчас в семье ты единственный здоровый мужчина, на тебя одна надежда, а то женщины растеряются, разохаются, женщины, они такие.

Мужчины ― они трусы!
Мы с подругой с удовольствием съели их бутерброды с колбасой, но с тех самых пор я верю, что мужчины ― они немного птицы.
Мужчины ― они, пардон, проще, понятнее, да и запросы у них поскромнее будут.
Я сказала: мужчина может ошибаться, мужчины, они, как дети, и надо это понимать.

У "женщин" чаще ставится запятая, у "мужчин" — тире, но в общем-то имеется знаковое (во всех смыслах) равноправие.

[§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания. Запятая — тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=190)